# Boostrap form-control class not wordwraping label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `Bootstrap 3.0` application and inside a form I have the following code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Keywords</h5>
            <div class="form-control" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>Declaratively walpurgisnacht station wellesley unsmudged cystomatous transfuse pecos nonconservative cocainise seaway unblasted gainsaid prewhipped. Adenomatous tzarevna fustily opelika counterblow balaamitical frogmouth damaskeening orthopneic carriable palaeontology postmyxedemic grandsire retouchtracing. Floor saturnalia bagwork semiacid drawl unregal cartouch predestinating curses traymobile quixotism antithesis fourpenny reshine. Gleamingly mongoloid ectrodactylous endostosis chromophil presagefully titillate cruise proairplane curaao montanan untappable flavius unintercepting. Gotha sarape halfpaced winnipegosis aphasia parotidean hydrate hatchetlike nonignitable shockingly changeable animi feces coerce</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" style="display: inline-block; width:80px" data-step="1">
                        Edit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

The result is the following image.

[image]

Here is the `form-control` style:

[image]

If you see my `<label>` has a lot of words and the problem I have is that the round background rectangle is not growing with the Word Wrap.

I marked with red the round background rectangle  that Im talking about.

[image]

> How can I make that background to grow in the same ratio?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the bootstrap classes in their intended way

`.form-control` has a fixed height. You could either change `.form-control` to not have a fixed height or add a custom class to change the height of the element. I recommend looking into the intended use of this and other bootstrap classes here:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Comment: Any clue on how to get the desired result in the correct way?

Comment: Just use a `row` instead of a `form-control`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `.form-control` class so that it doesn't have a fixed `height`. Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h4rnfhzt/), where I added `height:auto` to the `.form-control` class.